# Что значит <T> перед возвращаемым типом в методе

Tags: java, list, методы

Есть класс:

```
class Lists {
    public static <T> List<T> toList(T[] arr) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T elt : arr)
            list.add(elt);
        return list;
    }
}
```

`List<T>` - это тип, что вернет метод `toList`, но что значит `<T>` перед `List<T>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<T>` в начале описания метода нужен для того, чтобы указать, что `T` - это generic-тип, а не класс `T`. Пример:

```
private static class T
{
    public String str;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    first(list);
    second(list);
}

private static void first(List<T> list) { }

private static <T> void second(List<T> list) { }
```

`first(list)` вызовет ошибку, потому что созданный список - это `List<Integer>`, а не `List<T>`. `second(list)` же отработает без ошибок.

Comment: выходит, вопрос только в том, что `<T>` перед `List<T>` просто объясняет компилятору что такое `T`? Так можно проставить любую другую букву (M, P, G, D и т.д.)?

Comment: @TimurVI да. Более того, это не обязательно должна быть одна буква. `<Tratata>` тоже прекрасно отработает. А так как в методе может использоваться более одного generic-типа, то возможно и такое: `<A, B, C>`.

Comment: -  указание `generic`-типа `<T>` применяется только в методах? Почему в классах этого указания не требуется?

Comment: В классах вида `class Lists<T>{...` имею ввиду, почему не требуется уточнение

Comment: @TimurVI какое уточнение, и зачем оно нужно? При объявлении класса действует та же схема, что и в случае методов.

Comment: `@Regent`  то есть вполне применимо что-то вроде `class <T> Lists<T>{...` ?

Comment: @TimurVI нет, я про то, что запись `class Lists <T>` подразумевает, что в классе `Lists` будет использоваться generic-тип `T`, а не класс `T`. При объявлении класса generic-типы описываются после названия.

Comment: `@Regent вот этого понимания мне как раз не хватало, спасибо вам.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про Generics.

Например запись

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>
```

говорит о том что мы можем хранить в списке только объекты или значения типа String.

Comment: А как это связано с вопросом?

Comment: человеку, который не знаком с понятием generic, этот ответ даст минимальную пользу

Comment: как раз таки здесь мне понятно, смутило присутствие `<T>`, объяснение которого при чтении мною было видимо пропущено, а найти где не могу, вот и обратился в SO