# Есть документация к методам java, как называют описание типов?

Tags: java, терминология, документация

Есть документация к методам java и в этой документации есть описание правил какого типа параметры, какой тип возвращаемого значения. К примеру:

```
<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)
```

Как называются эти правила? Где можно посмотреть справку? порой вводят в ступор..

Comment: Вы имеете в виду [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) ?

Comment: @Dred ну вот к примеру тут R-как обобщенный тип, почему он стоит слева и справа, что это значит? или знак вопроса что значит?

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, примите его, нажав на галочку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищем дальше и, находим [generics wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) Да, соглашусь, что если не знаешь термины, то искать сложно, то, можно искать что-то типа "Java T и R перед названием класса", который приведет, например, [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/611474/216510) А дальше, можно снова вести поиски, уже по имеющимся терминам.

Кстати, откуда вы взяли эту строку? Но, например в [доках](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) можно увидеть `Interface Stream<T>` в самом начале, что значит, что Stream будет содержать элементы типа `T` о чем там же и написано

> Type Parameters:
>
> T - the type of the stream elements

Тут же, только [ниже](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) вы можете увидеть метод со странными буквами, что также означает тоже самое что и сверху.

> Type Parameters:
>
> R - the type of the result
>
> A - the intermediate accumulation type of the Collector

Также, может быть полезна статья [JavaRush](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questcollections.level05.lecture09)

Так что, ответом на ваш вопрос будет [Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). А потом практика полученных оттуда знаний и... дело привычки